# Is it OK to abbreviate Esperanto to Eo?

Tags: discussion

"Esperanto" is a very commonly word used on here, for obvious reasons. I sometimes abbreviate it as *Eo*, based on the ISO 639 code for it.

Is that too obscure?

Comment: In my opinion: If you don't have to pay per character you write, use 'Esperanto'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it is a bad idea, unless you have used the word "Esperanto" an awful lot of time in the same post. When someone has a question about Esperanto, he uses "Esperanto" in the Google search bar. Not using this keyword would make the questions and answers harder to find.